# How to converted $x^3+y^3=6xy$ to parametric equations?

Tags: calculus

How to converted $x^3+y^3=6xy$  to parametric equations?

The suggested solution is:

> $x=\frac{6t}{1+t^2}$

> $y=\frac{6t^2}{1+t^2}$

But what is the process?

Comment: Which "operation" do you mean?

Comment: Intersect with the line $y = tx$.

Comment: The denominators should be $1+t^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking $x=r \cos^{\frac{2}{3}} \phi$ and $y = r \sin^{\frac{2}{3}} \phi$ we obtain $r=6 \cos^{\frac{2}{3}} \phi \sin^{\frac{2}{3}} \phi$ and now it can be used for parametric represantation:
$$x=6\cos^{\frac{4}{3}} \phi \sin^{\frac{2}{3}} \phi$$
$$y=6\cos^{\frac{2}{3}} \phi \sin^{\frac{4}{3}} \phi$$

Comment: Why $r=6\:\cos ^{\frac{2}{3}}\:\phi \:\sin ^{\frac{2}{3}}\:\phi $?@zkutch

Comment: @ikigai. Put $x,y$ to your equation.

Comment: Thank you! @zkutch

Answer (score 1):

Let us write $s:=x+y$ and $p:=xy$ and recall that a pair $(p,s)$ exists (for some integers $x,y$) iff $s^2 \ge 4p$). Then
$$
s^3-3ps=x^3+y^3=6xy=6p \implies p=\frac{s^3}{3s+6}.
$$
At this point, we need the condition
$$
s^2 \ge 4p=\frac{4}{3}\cdot \frac{s^3}{s+2}.
$$
This inequality is equivalent to
$$
s^2 \left(1-\frac{4}{3}\cdot \frac{s}{s+2}\right) \ge 0 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{4}{3}\cdot \frac{s}{s+2} \le 1 \Longleftrightarrow s\le 6.
$$
Now, if you know the pair $(s,p)$ then the roots of $Z^2-sZ+p=0$ would be
$$
(x,y)=\left(\frac{s+\sqrt{s^2-4p}}{2},\frac{s-\sqrt{s^2-4p}}{2}\right).
$$
In our problem it will be the set of pairs
$$
\left\{\left(\frac{s+\sqrt{s^2-\frac{4}{3}\cdot \frac{s^3}{s+2}}}{2},\frac{s-\sqrt{s^2-\frac{4}{3}\cdot \frac{s^3}{s+2}}}{2}\right): s\le 6\right\},
$$
that is
$$
\left\{\left(\frac{s}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{6-s}{3s+6}}\right),\frac{s}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{6-s}{3s+6}}\right)\right): s\le 6\right\}.
$$